# Grouping by multiple values when using dynamic linq and fluent mongo causes a malformed map-reduce emit statement

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, dynamic-linq, fluent-mongo

I'm using dynamic link to run mapreduce queries and I'm running into a problem when trying to group by multiple values.  Check this out:

This works fine:

var query =
contentDeliveryAggregates.AsQueryable().Where("_id.CId == 1 && _id.CdaId == 1 && _id.From >= @0 && _id.To <= @1", reportRequest.FromDate, reportRequest.ToDate).
GroupBy("_id.CdaId", "it").
Select("new(key,Sum(value.BW) as Bandwidth)");

This does not:

var query =
contentDeliveryAggregates.AsQueryable().Where("_id.CId == 1 && _id.CdaId == 1 && _id.From >= @0 && _id.To <= @1", reportRequest.FromDate, reportRequest.ToDate).
GroupBy("new(_id.CdaId, _id.CId)", "it").
Select("new(key,Sum(value.BW) as Bandwidth)");

The linq is valid (it compiles fine), but I get a runtime error because the mapreduce statement is malformed.  Here's the map-reduce statement from the second query:

{ "mapreduce" : "Aggregates", "map" : { "$code" : "function() { emit({}this._id.CdaIdthis.*id.CId, {\"*$f0\": this.value.BW}); }" }, "reduce" : { "$code" : "function(key, values) {var *$f0 = 0;values.forEach(function(doc) {*$f0 += doc.*$f0;});return { \"*$f0\": _$f0};}" }, "query" : { "_id.CId" : 1, "_id.CdaId" : 1, "_id.From" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2012-02-01T08:00:00Z") }, "*id.To" : { "$lte" : ISODate("2012-02-11T08:00:00Z") } }, "finalize" : { "$code" : "function(key, value) { return { \"*$f0\": value._$f0};}" }, "limit" : 0, "out" : { "inline" : 1 } }

Check out that emit statement; it's messed up...

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the fluent driver?

Answer (score 0):

From the mongodb linq tutorial 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+LINQ+Tutorial

"Only LINQ queries that can be translated to an equivalent MongoDB query are supported. If you write a LINQ query that can't be translated you will get a runtime exception and the error message will indicate which part of the query wasn't supported."

Unfortunately group by is not in the supported list, hopefully someone will add it soon